# Qt QAbstractItemModel slow when scrolling in treeview

Tags: c++, qt, model-view

I made a simple model without any data, just showing some text. It works out okay if data returns a string. If I change it to return `QString("%1").arg(index.row());` it starts becoming slow when scrolling in my treeview.

```
QModelIndex CvMaskModel::index( int row, int column, const QModelIndex & parent ) const
{
    if(!hasIndex(row,column,parent))
        return QModelIndex();

    void * parentitem;
    if (!parent.isValid())
    {
        parentitem = m_rootmodel;

    }
    else
        parentitem = parent.internalPointer();

    if (parentitem == m_rootmodel)
    {
        //auto meta =m_rootmodel->data(m_rootmodel->index(row),MetaImageFile::MetaImageFileRole).value<MetaImageFile*>();
        return createIndex(row,column,m_root);
    }
    return QModelIndex();
    //TreeItem *parentItem;
    //if(!parent.isValid())
    ImageListModel* parentItem = static_cast<ImageListModel*>(parent.internalPointer());
    QString data;
    if(parentItem == m_rootmodel)
    {

        data = m_rootmodel->data(parentItem->index(row),MetaImageFile::MetaImageFileNameRole).toString();

    }
     switch(parent.column())
     {
     case 0:
         return createIndex(row,column,0);
     default:
          return QModelIndex();
     }


}
QModelIndex CvMaskModel::parent ( const QModelIndex & index ) const
{
     if (!index.isValid())
         return QModelIndex();

     root* parentItem = static_cast<root*>(index.internalPointer());
     if(parentItem)
         return QModelIndex();


     switch(index.column())
     {
     case 0:
         return QModelIndex();
     default:
          return QModelIndex();
     }



}
int CvMaskModel::rowCount ( const QModelIndex & parent ) const
{
    if (!parent.isValid())
        return m_rootmodel->rowCount();


    switch(parent.column())
    {
    case 0:
        return 1;
        //return m_masks.value(m_rootmodel->data(parent,MetaImageFile::MetaImageFileRole).value<MetaImageFile*>()).size();
    case 1:
        return 0;
    default:
        return 0;
    }

}
int CvMaskModel::columnCount ( const QModelIndex & /*parent*/  ) const
{
    return 3;
}
QVariant CvMaskModel::data ( const QModelIndex & index, int role ) const
{
    if (!index.isValid() || index.row() > m_rootmodel->rowCount())
        return QVariant();


    //if (role != Qt::DisplayRole)
    //     return QVariant();
    QVariant val;
    switch(index.column())
    {
    case 0:
        return QString("%1").arg(index.row());
        //val = m_rootmodel->data(index,MetaImageFile::MetaImageFileNameRole);
        //return val;
    case 1:
        return "HEJ";
    default:
        return QVariant();

    }
}
```

Comment: You could use QString::number instead. It should be faster since it doesn't have to parse the string for %1 and destroy an unnecessary temporary object.

Comment: Thanks. I just believed there was some other issue, that i did not understand. Dont understand why its slow. its only 500 rows.

Answer (score 2):

It is a QAbstractItemView issue indeed. I'm trying to solve this problem in a while without success. My problem is that I have a tree with a number of nodes in the order of milions. I did some tests to profile QTreeView and what I found was a little shoking. When you scroll down in the QTreeView it keep calling QAbstractItemModel::index() for every item already shown.

Say for instance you're viewing 20 itens. It was expected at least 20 calls do index(), but the tree view calls index() for **all** sibiling itens. When you scroll down it calls index() for everyone **again** and possibly more then once. If you hover the mouse in an item it calls index(). If you blink your eye it will call index() for every item.

My next step is to check how the QTreeView (in my case) calls its item model and try to implement a custom, optimized one.